# Create thumbnails in C++

Tags: c++, thumbnails

Wondering if anyone knows how to create thumbnails in C++ from NITF 2.1 images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the package below you should be able to read a NITF image and then generate your own smaller version to save as a thumbnail.

NITRO is a full-fledged, extensible library solution for reading and writing National Imagery Transmission Format (NITF) files, a U.S. Department of Defense standard format. It is written in cross-platform C, with bindings available for other languages (C++, Java, Python). NITRO was originally developed by General Dynamics - Advanced Information Systems in 2004 and is continuously being improved. It is now released as open-source software under the Lesser GNU Public License.

http://nitro-nitf.sourceforge.net/wikka.php?wakka=HomePage